# Jquery - How to unhide cell if selected in dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can't seem to wrap my head around this. I have a dropdown input that allows multiple select. When ever the "Other" option is selected it would unhide my cell and show an input to add additional details. I currently have this working with the script below however, if I select multiple options including "Other" it remains hidden. I need it to be able to unhide when ever it's selected, either with multiple options or if it's the only selected option.

Anyone have any ideas?

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nh3mL3sv/

SCRIPT:

```
$("#support").change(function(){
        if(jQuery.inArray('Other', $(this).val()) === 0)
        {
        $(".hidden").show();
        }
        else
        {
        $(".hidden").hide();
        }    
});
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Équipe:
        </td>
        <td >
            <select multiple id="support">
                <option value='1'> 1 </option>
                <option value='2'> 2 </option>
                <option value='3'> 3 </option>
                <option value='4'> 4 </option>
                <option value='5'> 5 </option>
                <option value='Other'> Other </option>
            </select>
        </td>   

        <td>
            <div class="hidden" style="display: none;"> 
                Autres:
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="hidden" style="display: none;">
                <input>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>                      
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because [`inArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) will return an integer of the position in the array. When there are many items in the array it could be at position 0 *or higher*. You are checking just the first position, you need to check all positions (*0 and larger*):

```
if(jQuery.inArray('Other', $(this).val()) >= 0)
```

This can also be checked by just making sure a value was found (not -1)

```
if(jQuery.inArray('Other', $(this).val()) != -1)
```

[**Fiddle Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/nh3mL3sv/1/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `indexOf` for this:

```
if ($(this).val().indexOf("Other") > -1) { 
    //Has "Other" selected.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The position of the index will change when people select different options. So when you pick it with one it will be at zero. When you select another one with it, it will be at one. So you want to check that the inArray does not return -1

Change

```
if(jQuery.inArray('Other', $(this).val()) === 0)
```

to

```
if(jQuery.inArray('Other', $(this).val()) !== -1)
```